Why do meteorites often look like a chain of individual dots?
I noticed that in many videos meteorites look like a chain of moving luminous points.
What could be the reason for this phenomenon?
Screenshots:






 Preview



0:24



0 - 0:40



0:08

Those aren't meteors,  they are airplane lights.  They look like a chain of dots on a timelapse because they are flashing.

That's not an exact duplicate, but the issue in your earlier question is essentially the same.  If you take a timelapse of the sky, you are likely to get some aircraft in the shot.

@JamesK  yes, these questions are similar, but they are not the same.
if these are airplanes, then I can’t imagine how such an image is obtained?
You can often encounter the opposite situation with a sufficiently long shutter speed, when a moving point becomes a luminous line.
But I can't imagine one point turning into several in one frame.

Because it's a strobe light, which is standard safety gear for flying a plane at night. It flashes for a fraction of a second, then goes dark for a couple of seconds. If you take a photo of that with a long shutter duration, you'll get a bright patch in each location where the flash happened with dark between, or possibly with a thinner streak of light between the flashes if the plane has strobes and a continuous light running. (Most airplanes don't use running lights at altitude, and turn them on when beginning descent, but it depends on the specific aircraft and on the pilot's choices.)

@DarthPseudonym    It is theoretically impossible to confuse an airplane with a meteorite, because their angular velocities differ by tens, or even a hundred times.  Which objects are then meteorites?
If these are planes, then they should be similar, but they look very different.
Moreover, there are too many planes in such a narrow area of space. Such a density of flights is only possible near large airports.

You can't tell the angular velocity of an object in a time lapse video. Anything moving faster than a star is just a streak because of the slow shutter speed. I honestly don't think anything in these videos is actually a meteor -- planes are much more common than meteors on an average night unless you've specifically picked out a section of sky to specifically avoid flight lanes.  These videos honestly do NOT show an unusually large number of overflights for a randomly selected sky view anywhere in north america, europe, or the UK.

If you have the interest to, you might want to get on flightaware.com/live and zoom in on different areas of the map -- it's shocking how many airliners are overflying any given area even in the middle of the night. You can find places -- the Amazon, Siberia, the middle of the Pacific, central Africa -- but NA and Europe are just packed with planes. (For the record, if this was anywhere near a major airport, it wouldn't be a handful of streaks across the sky in an hour or two; you'd see hundreds of those, just a constant flow of light tracing the paths in and out of that airspace.)

I have plenty of these on my night photos (meteors are much more rare) :). So from personal experience yes, they are airplanes.

Vladimir - those are very obviously planes, and as a pilot and aero enthusiast who has flightradar open almost all day every day, I can tell you that your comment re density only being like that near airports is just wrong.
